# @Font-face CSS Rule not working in Firefix 68.0.1

Tags: css, metadata, font-face

I am working with my site and using custom font; Ballet Harmony and until recently it was working. Now in the Firefox & Chrome Console says "CORS request not HTTP request" and will not show the font. There is nothing wrong with the font files, I tried re-downloading them but the error still occurs. How might I fix this error if at all possible? The Firefox CDN link didn't clear up the issue at all. I am open to all thoughts on a fix, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in the settings a way to disable this for local editing by typing in the address bar "about:config" and then searching "privacy.file_unique_origin" then double-clicking to disable that. The font now shows perfectly fine.